# What happens when you merge two branches with submodules?

Tags: git, git-branch

I have a repository with a submodule. The commit of the submodule in master branch of the parent module is different from the commits of the submodule in the feature branch of the parent module.

If I merge the feature branch into master, what commit with the submodule be at in master?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Git will report a merge conflict -- it has no way to decide which is right, if either. Taking the later version is often the right move, for instance when it's a pure support library.

Answer (score 0):

I think the merge will not touch the sub module, since the sub module directory is not part of the repository working tree it is separate repository in fact.